# Jstree no casrga hijos

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript, jstree

estoy intentando cargar un jstree por medio de un arreglo json creado a partir de multiples consultas, el problema radica en que genero el JSON con la estructura que lo requiere según la documentación, pero cuando ejecuto el código solo me carga los dos nodos padres y los hijos no, aquí esta mi código espero puedan ayudarme

Esto es typescript

```
   import { Component, OnInit } from '@angular/core';
import { ScriptLoaderService } from '../../../../_services/script-loader.service';
import { textoModuloAdm } from '../../../../texto';
import { Router } from "@angular/router";
import { AjaxService } from '../../../../_services/ajax.service';

import *  as TreeView from '../../../../../assets/js/treeViewRol';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-form-rol',
  templateUrl: './form-rol.component.html',
  styles: []
})
export class FormRolComponent implements OnInit {
  treeView: TreeView.TreeView = new TreeView.TreeView([], false);

  constructor(
    private _script: ScriptLoaderService,
    public texto: textoModuloAdm,
    private router: Router,
    private ajax_s: AjaxService,
  ) { }

  ngOnInit() {

    this.obtenerInformacionInicial().then((data: any) => {
      return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
        data.forEach((item) => {
          let child = [];
          let url = 'private/Permiso_Mod/' + item.id;
          console.log(url);
          this.ajax_s.getInfo(url, '').subscribe((modulos: any) => {
            modulos.result[0].forEach((modulo) => {

              child.push({
                //"id": modulo.idModulo,
                "text": modulo.nombreModulo,
                "parent": item.id
                //"icon": "icon-null",
              })
            })
            item.children = child;
          })
        })
        //console.log(data);
        resolve(data);
      }).then((tree) => {
        this.treeView.cargarTreeView({
          "core": {
            "data": tree
          },
          plugins: ["dnd", "state", "types", "checkbox"]
        });
      })

    })
  }

  obtenerInformacionInicial() {
    return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {

      this.ajax_s.getInfo('private/Modulo', '').subscribe((data) => {

        let modulos = data.result[0];
        let tree = [];
        let url = '';

        modulos.forEach((value, index) => {
          if (value.posicion.indexOf('.') == -1) {
            tree.push({
              //"id":'mod'+value.idModulo.toString(),
              //"id": "#",
              "text": value.nombreModulo,
              "parent": '#',
              "children": [],
              "icon": "fa fa-folder m--font-folderRol",
            })
          }

        })


        resolve(tree)

      })


    })

  }


y en el javascript esoty haciendo esto 

    cargarTreeView(tree) {
        console.log(tree);
        $('#treeViewRol').jstree(tree);
    }
```

PDTA: El Json que estoy generando es este: 
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Answer (score 0):

```
0:{id: 1, text: "Sistema", parent: "#"}
1:{id: 2, text: "Activo fijo", parent: 1}
2:{id: 3, text: "Transacciones", parent: 2}
```

Este es un ejemplo de un json que use para llenar un jsTree, veo que en tu codigo la propiedad id la tienes comentada y esa misma es el indicador para saber el **nodo padre** y hacer relación con la propiedad **parent**, en mi caso Sistema es el nodo principal, activo fijo su hijo y transacciones el nieto.